The problem with deployment with Argo CD in k3s: npm error Missing script: "start"
I am using argo cd to deploy on a server with k3s. The image I need to deploy works fine locally on my k8s device. But not on a server with k3s.
My Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth 
          image: My-username/auth
          env:
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: some-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'some-value'

My package.json
...
 "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache",
    "test:ci": "jest"
  },
...

but I see an error in the argo cd interface:
npm error Missing script: "start"
npm error
npm error Did you mean one of these?
npm error   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm error   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
npm error   npm run
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm_logs/2024-05-25T20_23_24_072Z-debug-0.log

The image is built using GitHub Actions
name: deploy-auth

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'auth/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          file: auth/Dockerfile
          tags: My-username/auth:latest
          platforms: linux/amd64

Moreover, if i create an image on my local device, the image is successfully launched on the server with Argo cd
I have seen that this problem often occurs due to an incorrect work folder, but in my case everything should be fine.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Does this image actually work locally?  I'd often expect the Typescript tools like ts-node-dev to be included in the devDependencies section, and npm install --only=prod wouldn't include them.  It'd help to include the actual error in plain text in the question.

@DavidMaze I tried to change it, but the result did not change

Changed tags since it seems the container build process was incorrect. The image should run the same in any environment after built... So if a local build worked, then you'd have to replicate that in GH actions.


Try adding checkout as the first step, this is necessary to copy the repository:

- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v3


And in the build-push-action parameters you should specify the context:

- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
  with:
    push: true
    context: ./auth
    file: ./auth/Dockerfile
    tags: your-docker-account-name/auth:latest


Wouldn't the build have failed without cloning or the correct context?

@OneCricketeer as it turned out, no
